# Django ORM and multiple annotations

Tags: python, django

How to get correctly result with multiple annotations?

when I type:

```
MyModel.objects.values('fk1__fk2__fk3__name').annotate(x=Count('fk1__items'))
```

I get

```
<QuerySet [
  {'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name1', 'x': 1}, 
  {'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name2', 'x': 2778}
]>
```

When I type:

```
MyModel.objects.values('fk1__fk2__fk3__name').annotate(x=Count('fk1__fk2__fk3__name'))
```

I get

```
<QuerySet [
  {'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name1', 'x': 1}, 
  {'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name2', 'x': 33}
]>
```

But when I'm trying to connect this two annotations I get different results:

```
MyModel.objects.values('fk1__fk2__fk3__name').annotate(x=Count('fk1__fk2__fk3__name'), y=Count('fk1__items'))

Out[43]: <QuerySet [
  {'y': 1, 'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name1', 'x': 1}, 
  {'y': 2778, 'fk1__fk2__fk3__name': u'Name2', 'x': 2778}
]>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try to add `order_by()` to reset default order by in your model

Comment: its not about order, I have wrong number in Name2. Should be 33 instead 2778.